# Selenium python- skip an iteration if a web element is not present

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, iteration

Selenium python- skip an iteration if a web element is not present

Please I'm trying to fetch data from https://b2b.baidu.com/ after inputting a keyword in a search field on the website. I want to skip an iteration if an element is not present on the first page.

I know this can work seamlessly but I'm still a novice and can't figure out what I'm doing wrongly at the moment. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**Here is what I've done:**

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import time
import pandas as pd


website = 'https://b2b.baidu.com/'
path = "C:/Users/ICT/chromedriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()

# the search terms which contains location and keyword are from a dataframe in another file
from baidu_locations import location_key_row
from baidu_locations import location_data_col
from baidu_locations import key_data_col


for i in range(1, 6):
    
    
    website = []
    rep_name = []
    contact = []
    location = []
    keyword = []
    business_name = []

    # Input location and keyword
    enter_query = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='我要采购…']")))
    enter_query.clear()    
    enter_query.send_keys(location_key_row[i-1])

    location_query = location_data_col[i-1]
    location.append(location_query)
    keyword_query = location_data_col[i-1]
    keyword.append(keyword_query)
        
    search_type = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class='search-type']")))
    search_type.click()
# If *```company_url```* element is not available, I want to go back to the next *```enter_query```* and continue the iteration.
    try:    
        company_url = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.title-container > span > span.name > a')))
        website.append(company_url.get_property('href'))
                      
        first_location = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//span[@class="title link"])[1]')))
        first_location.click()
        
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        
        name = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='shop-contact-warp shop-contact-vertical-warp'] div[class='top'] div span[class='show-name']")))
        business_name.append(name.text)
        #print(reps)
        
        representative = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.shop-index-new-right> div > div.top > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.text > p.sub-text")))
        rep_name.append(representative.text)
        
        phone_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'查看电话')]")))
        phone_option.click()
        
        popup_contact = driver.window_handles[1]
        driver.switch_to.window(popup_contact)
        
        phone_number = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[class="phone"]')))
        contact.append(phone_number.text)
        #print(contact_no)
        
        
        time.sleep(2)
        
        return_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'返回')]")))
        return_button.click()
        driver.close()
        
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
  except:
        continue    
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': location, 'Keyword': keyword, 'Name': business_name, 'Representative': rep_name, 'Phone': contact, 'Link': website})
````

So if the *`company_url`* variable element is *present* on the first page, I want to click on it, go to the new tab and copy the data on that page and return to the first tab and *repeat* the process.
If the element variable *`company_url`* is *not present*, I want to skip that iteration and input the next search term *`enter_query`* from the specified range.

I want to fetch the data of *`enter_query`* where *`company_url`* element is present and save in a dataframe.

This code block seems to only fetch one row of data no matter the range I set.
Thank you for your help. Kindly let me know if my question is not clear or any questions you might have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zJKQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you only want to loop in specific conditions. In that case, why not increment iterator only when satisfied your conditions?

Hope below could be a help

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

website = "https://b2b.baidu.com/"
path = "C:/Users/ICT/chromedriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()

# the search terms which contains location and keyword are from a dataframe in another file
from baidu_locations import key_data_col, location_data_col, location_key_row

# ------------- added -------------
i = index_from = 1
index_to = 6
# ---------------------------------


# ------------------ modified ------------------
while i < index_to:
# ----------------------------------------------
    website = []
    rep_name = []
    contact = []
    location = []
    keyword = []
    business_name = []

    # Input location and keyword
    enter_query = wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='我要采购…']"))
    )
    enter_query.clear()
    enter_query.send_keys(location_key_row[i - 1])

    location_query = location_data_col[i - 1]
    location.append(location_query)
    keyword_query = location_data_col[i - 1]
    keyword.append(keyword_query)

    search_type = wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class='search-type']"))
    )
    search_type.click()

    # ------------------ modified ------------------
    try:
        company_url = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.title-container > span > span.name > a",
                )
            )
        )
    except:
        continue
    
    try:
    # ----------------------------------------------
        website.append(company_url.get_property("href"))

        first_location = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//span[@class="title link"])[1]'))
        )
        first_location.click()

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

        name = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "div[class='shop-contact-warp shop-contact-vertical-warp'] div[class='top'] div span[class='show-name']",
                )
            )
        )
        business_name.append(name.text)
        # print(reps)

        representative = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "div.shop-index-new-right> div > div.top > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.text > p.sub-text",
                )
            )
        )
        rep_name.append(representative.text)

        phone_option = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'查看电话')]"))
        )
        phone_option.click()

        popup_contact = driver.window_handles[1]
        driver.switch_to.window(popup_contact)

        phone_number = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[class="phone"]'))
        )
        contact.append(phone_number.text)
        # print(contact_no)

        time.sleep(2)

        return_button = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'返回')]"))
        )
        return_button.click()
        driver.close()

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        
        # ------------- added -------------
        # No problem here
        i += 1
        # ---------------------------------
    except:
        continue

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Location": location,
            "Keyword": keyword,
            "Name": business_name,
            "Representative": rep_name,
            "Phone": contact,
            "Link": website,
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. When I run your code, it picks the first row on file from `enter_query` element. After that iteration, it goes into an infinite loop of the same search keywords. Please what could be the reason for this, because I didn't have this issue before?